# How to self invoke the tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I m new to GUI and Tkinter.

I m trying to invoke a function or script without pressing a button from the GUI.
It should run the function as soon as the GUI opens.

```
def example_fun():
    print("this does something...")

img0 = PhotoImage(file = f"img0.png")
b0 = Button(
    image = img0,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    command = example_fun,
    relief = "flat")
```

What is the best way to run the script as soon as GUI opens?

Comment: So the idea is that when the button is clicked, `example_fun` will run. The goal is to make the same thing happen at the start of the script, i.e., make `example_fun` run. So... how do you *normally* cause functions to run? By... *calling* them, right? Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run (also referred to as call) the function once when the code first runs by simply calling the function in the main body. Something like

```
example_fun()
b0 = Button(
    master = root,
    image = img0,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    command = example_fun,
    relief = "flat")
```

will call your function once, while also assigning the same function to your button. Note you were missing the parent argument in your `Button`, I added it in for you.

Comment: Thanks, I added b0.invoke() after this and it worked like a charm!

Comment: You shouldn't need `b0.invoke()` as well as `example_fun()`. If you are, you are actually calling your function twice. Use either of the two options as both will work

Answer (score 0):

The `main` Python term usually describes the part of code where there is no identation because that is the main scope. In this code `example_fun()` at the end of your code with no identation to get that running. But this code won't pass the interpreter because `main()` in that function is calling a function `main` that is not defined here.

Comment: Edited, but this will require me to press the button to run the function. I want the code to run itself once the GUI opens.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but could be explained a lot better

Comment: Yes I didn't explain well -  you don't even need a button if you call your function directly in the main scope.